# Debug Eclipse - Classes com nomes iguais em projetos diferentes

Tags: java, eclipse, debug

Estava fazendo o debug aqui e me deparei com uma situação curiosa. Já fucei, mas não consegui êxito em descobrir o problema.

Em um projeto, tenho a classe `EntidadeDAO` no **projeto1**. Em outro projeto, no mesmo workspace, tenho uma classe com o mesmo nome, `EntidadeDAO`, no **projeto2**.
Ao fazer o debug no **projeto1**, nessa classe, o eclipse aponta para a classe do **projeto2**.

obs: As duas classes são bastante diferentes, **somente os nomes são iguais**. Somente os nomes mesmo. O nome do projeto e pacotes são todos diferentes.

Mais alguém já passou por essa situação e sabe me dizer o motivo?

edit: Estou usando o Eclipse Neon, esqueci de avisar.

Comment: Pode ser o import de `EntidadeDAO` aponte para o projeto dois. Como vc adicionou essa classe no projeto? como arquivo normal ou library?

Comment: está no mesmo pacote, o `package faturamento;`

Comment: Mesmo que o projeto 2 esteja fechado acontece isso? veja também se no projeto 1 não tem nenhum tipo referência para o projeto 2. Verifica o build path.

Comment: Não, não tem nenhuma referência ao outro projeto no build path.

Comment: Não testei fechá-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Esse problema ocorre pois na configuração de debug do eclipse o projeto1 esta primeiro que o projeto2, isso é meio que um bug do eclipse mesmo e muita gente que tem classes que tem o mesmo nome em vários projetos tem esse problema de vez em quando, eu já consegui resolver isso de duas formas:

**1º Opção: Alterar a ordem do Source Lookup no debug.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2º Opção: Em vez de alterar a ordem remova um dos projetos do Source Lookup temporariamente**

Comment: Valeu cara!!!

Verifiquei `Run/Debug Settings`, onde tem a lista de classes que estão no Debug e achei outra solução. 

Posso editar a `launch configuration properties` da classe e apontar para o projeto que eu quero e a classe que eu quero.